# ¿Cómo insertar un gran número de registros en una tabla?

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Tengo un "pequeño" problema, lo que pasa es que quiero insertar más de 100.000 registros, y por ende tarda bastante, este es mi código:

```
private void guardar(VivVectorPreciosValmer precio, Connection connection) {


    String sql="insert  into TVIV048_CARGAVEC (TO_ACCIONES, ST_PRECIOACT, IM_BURSATIL, TO_CALIFICACION, TP_CUPON, DU_DIASVENCER, NB_EMISORA, ST_ESTADO, CT_PUENTE, NU_VALUA, NU_INDICE, IM_INTDIAANT, IM_INTCIERMES, IM_INTMISDIA, DU_PLAZO, IM_PRECIOLIMPIO, IM_MISMODIA, IM_PRECIOSUCIO, IM_ULTIMOANO, IM_ULTIMOMES, NB_SERIE, IM_SOBRETASA, IM_TASADESC, TP_MERCADO, TP_REGISTRO, TP_VALOR) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


    VivVectorPreciosValmerId id = precio.getId();

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setDouble(1, id.getAcciones());
        ps.setString(2, id.getActPrecio());
        ps.setDouble(3, id.getBursatilidad());
        ps.setString(4, id.getCalificacion());
        ps.setDouble(5, id.getCupon());
        ps.setDouble(6, id.getDiasVencer());
        ps.setString(7, id.getEmisora());
        ps.setString(8, id.getEstado());
        ps.setDouble(9, id.getFechaValor());
        ps.setDouble(10, id.getFechaValuacion());
        ps.setDouble(11, id.getIndice());
        ps.setDouble(12, id.getIntereses24Horas());
        ps.setDouble(13, id.getInteresesCM());
        ps.setDouble(14, id.getInteresesMismoDia());
        ps.setDouble(15, id.getPlazo());
        ps.setDouble(16, id.getPrecioLimpio());
        ps.setDouble(17, id.getPrecioMismoDia());
        ps.setDouble(18, id.getPrecioSucio());
        ps.setDouble(19, id.getPrecioUltimoAnio());
        ps.setDouble(20, id.getPrecioUltimoMes());
        ps.setString(21, id.getSerie());
        ps.setDouble(22, id.getSobretasa());
        ps.setDouble(23, id.getTasaDes());
        ps.setString(24, id.getTipoMercado());
        ps.setString(25, id.getTipoRegistro());
        ps.setString(26, id.getTipoValor());

        ps.execute();

        ps.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public MensajesProceso cargaHAHB(String fechaInicio, Integer idUsuario) {

    MensajesProceso mensajesProceso = new MensajesProceso();

    VivProceso procesoHA = getProcesoHAHC(fechaInicio);
    VivProceso procesoHB = this.obtenerProceso(Procesos.CARGAR_HB);

    Date fecha = null;
    SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    SimpleDateFormat formatoTiempo = new SimpleDateFormat("kkmmss");
    try {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        fecha = dateFormat.parse(fechaInicio);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Conversión de fecha : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    fechaInicio = formatoFecha.format(fecha) + formatoTiempo.format(new Date());


    VivCntrl vivCntrl = new VivCntrl();
    VivCntrlId vivCntrlId = new VivCntrlId();
    vivCntrlId.setFevento(fechaInicio);
    vivCntrlId.setIaplica(Operacion.ACTUALIZAR_VECTOR_PRECIOS_VALMER);
    vivCntrlId.setIusuario(idUsuario);
    vivCntrlId.setStermino('I');
    vivCntrl.setId(vivCntrlId);
    this.genericDao.guardar(vivCntrl);

    File haFile=new File(path+procesoHA.getArchivo());
    File hbFile=new File(path+procesoHB.getArchivo());

    VectorValmerMarshall haM=new HAMarshallImpl();
    VectorValmerMarshall hbM=new HBMarshallImpl();

    int haTotal=15;
    int total=3000;
    int hbTotal=200;
    boolean termino=true;

    Connection connection=null;
    try {
        connection = this.dataSource.getConnection();
        logger.info("A ver que pedo...");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Error al obtener la coneccion", e);
    }

    try{

        logger.info("Vaciando tabla del vector");
        this.genericDao.borrarTabla("VivVectorPreciosValmer");


        logger.info("Iniciando proceso para HA");
        List<VivVectorPreciosValmer> data = haM.doMarshall(haFile);
        haTotal = data.size();
        total = 0;
        logger.info("Por insertar HA");
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        for (VivVectorPreciosValmer precio : data) {

            VivVectorPreciosValmerId precioId=precio.getId();

            if("D".equalsIgnoreCase(precioId.getEstado()) && !("CEPLATA".equalsIgnoreCase(precioId.getEmisora())&& "*".equalsIgnoreCase(precioId.getSerie())) ){
                precioId.setIndice(0.0D);
                precioId.setFechaValor(0.0D);
                precioId.setFechaValuacion(Double.parseDouble(fechaInicio.substring(0, 8)));
                if(!verificaNull(precio)){
                    this.guardar(precio,connection);
                    //this.genericDao.guardar(precio);
                    total++;
                    if(total%500==0){
                        connection.commit();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        connection.commit();

        logger.info("Iniciando proceso para HB");
        data=hbM.doMarshall(hbFile);
        hbTotal = data.size();
        logger.info("Por insertar HB");
        for (VivVectorPreciosValmer precio : data) {

            VivVectorPreciosValmerId precioId=precio.getId();

            if("D".equalsIgnoreCase(precioId.getEstado()) && !("CEPLATA".equalsIgnoreCase(precioId.getEmisora())&& "*".equalsIgnoreCase(precioId.getSerie())) ){
                precioId.setFechaValuacion(Double.parseDouble(fechaInicio.substring(0, 8)));
                if(!verificaNull(precio)){
                    this.guardar(precio,connection);
                    //this.genericDao.guardar(precio);
                    total++;
                    if(total%500==0){
                        connection.commit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        logger.info("Primera regla HB");
        this.genericDao.queryGenericoSQL("update tviv048_cargavec set im_preciosucio=im_tasadesc where nb_emisora='CETES' and im_preciosucio=0");
        logger.info("Segunda regla HB");
        this.genericDao.queryGenericoSQL("delete tviv048_cargavec where nb_emisora='CETES' and tp_valor='CBI'");
        logger.info("Tercera regla HB");
        this.genericDao.queryGenericoSQL("update tviv048_cargavec set tp_valor='BI' where nb_emisora='CETES' and tp_valor in ('B','CB')");
        logger.info("Cuarta regla HB");
        this.genericDao.queryGenericoSQL("update tviv048_cargavec set nb_emisora='BONDES' where nb_emisora='BONDESD'");
        logger.info("Quinta regla HB");
        this.genericDao.queryGenericoSQL("update tviv048_cargavec set im_preciosucio=round( ( ( (to_number(nb_serie) / 36000) * im_tasadesc) * 100),6) where nb_emisora='BANCARI' and tp_valor='GEI'");
        logger.info("Sexta regla HB");
        this.genericDao.queryGenericoSQL("update tviv048_cargavec set im_preciosucio = im_preciosucio * 100 where tp_valor in ('G','I')");
        //Esta línea se repite por análisis de código en PB.
        logger.info("Septima regla HB");
        this.genericDao.queryGenericoSQL("update tviv048_cargavec set im_preciosucio = im_preciosucio * 100 where tp_valor in ('G','I')");


    }catch(Exception e){
        try {
            connection.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            logger.error("Error al hacer rollback", e);
        }
        termino=false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if(connection!=null && !connection.isClosed()){
            connection.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Error al hacer close", e);
    }

    mensajesProceso.setGravados(total + 1);
    mensajesProceso.setLeidos(haTotal+hbTotal);

    //Tabla Control
    String fechaFinProceso = fechaInicio.substring(0,8) + formatoTiempo.format(new Date());
    String query;
    if(termino) {
        query = "UPDATE TVIV006_CONTROL SET cd_FEVENTO=" + fechaFinProceso + ", nb_STERMINO='T' WHERE cd_IAPLICA='" + Operacion.ACTUALIZAR_VECTOR_PRECIOS_VALMER + "' AND cd_FEVENTO='" + fechaInicio + "'";
    } else {
        query = "UPDATE TVIV006_CONTROL SET cd_FEVENTO=" + fechaFinProceso + ", nb_STERMINO='E' WHERE cd_IAPLICA='" + Operacion.ACTUALIZAR_VECTOR_PRECIOS_VALMER + "' AND cd_FEVENTO='" + fechaInicio + "'";
    }
    genericDao.queryGenericoSQL(query);


    return mensajesProceso;
}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para reducir el tiempo de ejecución en inserciones?

Comment: Usa hilos y pool de conexiones aunque si los datos vienen de otras tablas, no necesitas hacerlo en java sino un `insert select ...`

Comment: @JUAN JOSE BUSTAMANTE SOLIS Podrias usar un bulk insert

Comment: El codigo este tiene deficiencias. No uses un prepare statement si no vas a hacer mas de un insert por vez. No abras y cierres la conexion para hacer siempre lo mismo. No generes una nueva cadena de insert por cada insert, si no que pasale los nuevos parametros.

Comment: Agregaría a todo lo que dijo @gbianchi, que uses transacciones.

Comment: Hola, Como podria realizarlo? en base al codigo que proporcione, donde podria empezar??

Comment: Has todas esas cosas que te dije. No voy a refactorizarte todo el codigo, porque ademas hacer un tunning completo requeriria tener los datos, no solamente tocar el codigo.

Comment: Va que va amigos, gracias por sus recomendaciones, saludos a todos.